# How do I avoid using ember metamorph?

Tags: ember.js

I'm iterating through a collection that I defined in my controller.

I'm using a foundation orbit plugin to turn this into a carousel.

However my HTML is getting mangled and it's ruining the plugin because it expects a certain output.

```
<ul class="orbit-slides-container" data-orbit="" style="margin-left: -800%; width: 1000%; height: 217px;"><script id="metamorph-3-end" type="text/x-placeholder" data-orbit-slide="" style="width: 10%;"></script>
      <script id="metamorph-3-start" type="text/x-placeholder" class="" style="width: 10%;"></script><script id="metamorph-1-start" type="text/x-placeholder" style="width: 10%;" class=""></script>
        <li style="width: 10%;" class="">
          <script id="metamorph-4-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>true<script id="metamorph-4-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
          <img src="source">
        </li>
      <script id="metamorph-1-end" type="text/x-placeholder" style="width: 10%;" class=""></script><script id="metamorph-2-start" type="text/x-placeholder" style="width: 10%;" class=""></script>
        <li style="width: 10%;" class="">
          <script id="metamorph-5-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>true<script id="metamorph-5-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
          <img src="src">
        </li>
      <script id="metamorph-2-end" type="text/x-placeholder" style="width: 10%;" class=""></script><script id="metamorph-3-end" type="text/x-placeholder" style="width: 10%;" class="active"></script>
    <script id="metamorph-3-start" type="text/x-placeholder" data-orbit-slide="" style="width: 10%;"></script></ul>
```

How do I avoid my HTML from getting mangled? Basically remove all the metamorph stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform custom rendering of a view that avoids the use of metamorph.

[Here is a blog](http://eviltrout.com/2013/04/01/adding-to-discourse-part-3.html) post discussing custom rendering of views in ember. (This is slightly dated but the core part on custom rendering is relevant)

If you define a `render` method on a view, whatever is `push`ed into the `buffer` argument is put in the DOM.

```
Discourse.HotnessView = Discourse.View.extend({
  classNames: ['hotness-control'],

  render: function(buffer) {
    for (var i=1; i<12; i++) {
      buffer.push("<button value='" + i + "'");
      if (this.get('hotness') === i) {
        buffer.push(" class='selected'");
      }
      buffer.push(">" + i + "</button>");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [unbound Handlebars helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_unbound).